# Confirmation dialog when opening multiple files

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

Sometimes while selecting multiple file (holding Shift) I accidentally double click, very fast but it's considered as double click nonetheless.

Is there setting in some Nautilus configuration file, where I can set dialogue to pop if I double click on multiple selected files?

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate solution. Why is it marked for closure?

Comment: Question has not attracted any attention. Will remove flag and check back in a week or so.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's really viewed by just few and OTOH it's so terrible situation when I accidentally open many files at once. I wish there is easy solution, as I even changed my mouse in a hope to solve it, but still it's same - sometimes click for dragging or just additionally selecting items in Nautilus is treated as double-click and then I sit, waiting for windows/memory bloat :S

Answer (score 1):

At present there is no setting in nautilus to adjust for a fast double click when selecting multiple items.

Nautilus does have a [Brainstorm page](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/nautilus/) for ideas so maybe you can add your request there.

To overcome the issue I suggest you adjust your mouse double click timeout response to a longer setting.

[image: Mouse settings]

Comment: I tried to set sensitivity when I first experienced the problem, w/o success. I don't think I actually press twice, it's just like Nautilus behaves like that - that's why I thought it must be some problem with my mouse, but after I changed it it's same. Brainstorm is good idea and I'll expose my issue, and link here in next couple of hours. Thanks